# Is saying "Thank you for the results" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have received an e-mail about some test results from other company. So, T would like to know how to say "thank you" to them politely? Do you have any better sentences?

Comment: "Thank you for sending me the test results."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is very little context given, and, unfortunately, if enough context were given to give a good answer, it would be a request for writing assistance.  So I answered in a comment.  Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

"Thank you for the results" is grammatically correct, but on one hand, it could sound like you are thanking people for having created good results from some activity.  I would clarify the statement by saying, "Thanks for SENDING the results" because you are thanking the action of sending, not the results in and of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it. I would comsider it an appropriate response to use in a professional atmosphere.